# Angular toggle class to parent element

Tags: angularjs

For angular I'm using a Directive to Toggle Class:

```
app.directive('toggleClass', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                element.toggleClass(attrs.toggleClass);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And the HTML I have multiple times:

```
<div class="tab" toggle-class="open">
    <div class="title">
        <p>Tab title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <!-- This element hidden by default, needs toggle -->
        <p>Foobar</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

It works, but when I click somewhere in the `.content`-element, it also toggles. But I want it to stay active. Not toggle-ing back to the close-state.

Is there an easy way to let it work like this:
- click on `.title`
- toggle `.content` (by adding `.open` to the `.tab`-element.

Answer (score 0):

I just consider that you don't need a custom directive to do this kind of things.

Here is two exemples, first one with the angular way to toggleClass, second one in a global angular way.

Both will meet your needs covered by this directive.

**First One :**

```
<div ng-repeat="aTab in [{},{},{},{},{}]" class="tab" ng-class="{'open':isOpen}">
      <div class="title" ng-click="isOpen = !isOpen">
          <p>Tab title</p>
      </div>
      <div class="content">
          <!-- This element hidden by default, needs toggle -->
          <p>Foobar</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

with this CSS

```
.content {
  display:none;
}
.open .content {
  display:block;
}
```

**Second one :**

```
<div ng-repeat="aTab in [{},{},{},{},{}]" class="tab">
      <div class="title" ng-click="aTab.show = !aTab.show">
          <p>Tab title</p> 
      </div>
      <div class="content2" ng-show="aTab.show">
          <!-- This element hidden by default, needs toggle -->
          <p>Foobar</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

You can see theses exemples in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yYiuhbYhrjooTgCvSkyX?p=preview)

Hope it helped

EDIT : Updated the exemples and plunker to show how it works with an ng-repeat

Comment: @User1469734 your solution isn't  an angular way. Could you gimme your try with multiple tabs ? You just have to make the var dynamic. (In your ng-repeat)

Comment: @user1469734 I updated my exemples and plunker to show how it works with an ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

Added `.parent()`

```
app.directive('toggleClass', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('click', function() {
                element.parent().toggleClass(attrs.toggleClass);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

And toggle-class to the `title` element.

```
<div class="tab">
    <div class="title" toggle-class="open">
        <p>Tab title</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <!-- This element hidden by default, needs toggle -->
        <p>Foobar</p>

    </div>
</div>
```